# jQuery - Getting div content and mutiply by input value

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to achieve a simple multiplication on my page.

This is what I have:

HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" title="Qty" class="input-text qty">
    <span class="price">$2</span>
    <div class="total"></div>
```

jQuery

```
     $('input[name="qty"]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('span.price"]').val();
     var b = $(this).val();
     $('.total"]').val(a * b);
     });
```

-Basically what happens is the input#qty is the field that users put in themselves
-The span.price is where the price is updated on, the span.price is updated as you add in more options to the product
-.total is the div where the total will be shown from the quantity * price.

I know this is all possible with jQuery I've just spent many hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: Not sure if you just made a typo, but you have extra characters in your selectors. `'.total"]'` should be `.total`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `span` and `div` do not have `values` (they are not input fields). You can use `.text()` to get/set their contents. Also, your `.total` and `span.price` selectors are incorrect, you need to remove the `"]`:

```
 $('input[name="qty"]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('span.price').text();
     var b = this.value;
     $('.total').text(a * b);
 });
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmnXT/3/)

---

#### edit

You can use `replace` to remove the dollar from your `span.price`:

```
var a = $('span.price').text().replace('$', '');
```

Or, for something more robust you can replace anything that is not a digit, or a period (`.`):

```
var a = $('span.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
```

Comment: That works! The span.price actually display $ amounts (i.e $2.89). Anyway it can take that and multiple in a dollar format?

Answer (score 1):

use `text()` or `html()` to get the text inside a html tag..**`.val()` is used to get/set the value of input elements only**..

try this

```
  var a = $('span.price"]').text();  //<---here
  var b = $(this).val();
  $('.total').text(a * b);
         //---^^^^---here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('input[name=qty]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('span.price').html();
     var b = $(this).val();
     $('.total').html(a * b);
     });
```

Try above code this will work for you.

Comment: That works too! I actually forgot to mention that the span.price actually has a format like $9.34 .. Is there any way to multiple it by the quantity input box?

Comment: @Gerardo yes you can remove the $ by using the `substr()` function. You need to use the `a.substr(1);` use it this will remove the $ sign.

Answer (score 1):

Form html tag you can not get any value. For that you need to use .html() method.

```
$('input[name=qty]').keyup(function() {
 var a = $('span.price').html();
 var b = $(this).val();
 $('.total').html(parseInt(a) *parseInt(b));
 });
```

Or you can write directly with out parstInt

```
$('input[name=qty]').keyup(function() {
 var a = $('span.price').html();
 var b = $(this).val();
 $('.total').html(parseInt(a) *parseInt(b));
 });
```

Enjoy.....!!! :)